# Is it possible to find two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ and $g$ for which $x = f(x)g(x)$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Is it possible to find two differentiable functions $f$ and $g$ and $g$ for which $x = f(x)g(x)$ and $f(0) = g(0) = 0$?

The fact that both functions have to be differentiable makes this a little more complicated, but we can say $\lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} =  \lim_{x \to a} \dfrac{\frac{x}{g(x)}-\frac{a}{g(a)}}{x-a}$ which has to be defined everywhere. Similarly with $g$. How can I prove this is possible?

Comment: $1=f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x)$ Plug $x=0$ and get a contradiction.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing that such functions exist, differentiating the equality yields $$\forall x, 1=f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x)$$

Plugging $x=0$ yields $1=0+0$, a contradiction.

Comment: What about $f = g = 0$?

Comment: @user19405892 in that case $fg=0\neq Id$

Answer (score 3):

You cannot even have **one** of them being differentiable (the other one just continuous). Indeed, assume $f$ is differentiable. Then
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{g(x)} = \infty.
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: If$ f=g=0$ then $f\cdot g\neq x$

Comment: Sure. If $x\equiv 0$. ;o) Damn, what a ridiculous mistake of mine. I will edit this.